# Is there a way to pass the request parameter to the /health endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am writing a custome Health Indicator to check the connectivity to another app. however to check this I require some request parameter in the request URL of /health endpoint.(e.g. URL that i want is "/health?countryCode=IN")
is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the `HttpServletRequest` object injected like:

```java
public class CustomHealthIndicator{
    
    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

}
```

And to get parameter:

```java
request.getParameter("countryCode")
```

Comment: Just to mention the typo, it's
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired